# How does the Objective-C runtime retrieve the list of classes and methods?

Tags: objective-c, assembly, objective-c-runtime

If I get the following Objective-C source file:

```
// test.m
#import <objc/Object.h>

@interface MySuperClass: Object {

}
-(void) myMessage1;
@end

@implementation MySuperClass
-(void) myMessage1 {

}
@end

@interface MyClass: MySuperClass {

}
-(void) myMessage2;
@end

@implementation MyClass
-(void) myMessage2 {

}
@end

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

and try to generate an assembly file from it with `clang -fobjc-nonfragile-abi -fnext-runtime -S test.m`, I get the following assembly code:

```
    .file   "test.m"
    .text
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _2D__5B_MySuperClass_20_myMessage1_5D_,@function
_2D__5B_MySuperClass_20_myMessage1_5D_: # @"\01-[MySuperClass myMessage1]"
.Ltmp0:
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rsp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rsp)
    ret
.Ltmp1:
    .size   _2D__5B_MySuperClass_20_myMessage1_5D_, .Ltmp1-_2D__5B_MySuperClass_20_myMessage1_5D_
.Ltmp2:
    .cfi_endproc
.Leh_func_end0:

    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _2D__5B_MyClass_20_myMessage2_5D_,@function
_2D__5B_MyClass_20_myMessage2_5D_:      # @"\01-[MyClass myMessage2]"
.Ltmp3:
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rsp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rsp)
    ret
.Ltmp4:
    .size   _2D__5B_MyClass_20_myMessage2_5D_, .Ltmp4-_2D__5B_MyClass_20_myMessage2_5D_
.Ltmp5:
    .cfi_endproc
.Leh_func_end1:

    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
.Ltmp6:
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $0, -4(%rsp)
    ret
.Ltmp7:
    .size   main, .Ltmp7-main
.Ltmp8:
    .cfi_endproc
.Leh_func_end2:

    .type   L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_,@object # @"\01L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_"
    .section    "__TEXT,__objc_classname,cstring_literals","aw",@progbits
L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_:
    .asciz   "MySuperClass"
    .size   L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_, 13

    .type   l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass,@object # @"\01l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_const","aw",@progbits
    .align  8
l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass:
    .long   1                       # 0x1
    .long   40                      # 0x28
    .long   40                      # 0x28
    .zero   4
    .quad   0
    .quad   L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .size   l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass, 72

    .type   OBJC_METACLASS_$_MySuperClass,@object # @"OBJC_METACLASS_$_MySuperClass"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_data","aw",@progbits
    .globl  OBJC_METACLASS_$_MySuperClass
    .align  8
OBJC_METACLASS_$_MySuperClass:
    .quad   OBJC_METACLASS_$_Object
    .quad   OBJC_METACLASS_$_Object
    .quad   _objc_empty_cache
    .quad   _objc_empty_vtable
    .quad   l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass
    .size   OBJC_METACLASS_$_MySuperClass, 40

    .type   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_,@object # @"\01L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_"
    .section    "__TEXT,__objc_methname,cstring_literals","aw",@progbits
L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_:
    .asciz   "myMessage1"
    .size   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_, 11

    .type   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_,@object # @"\01L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_"
    .section    "__TEXT,__objc_methtype,cstring_literals","aw",@progbits
L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_:
    .asciz   "v16@0:8"
    .size   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_, 8

    .type   l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MySuperClass,@object # @"\01l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MySuperClass"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_const","aw",@progbits
    .align  8
l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MySuperClass:
    .long   24                      # 0x18
    .long   1                       # 0x1
    .quad   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_
    .quad   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_
    .quad   _2D__5B_MySuperClass_20_myMessage1_5D_
    .size   l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MySuperClass, 32

    .type   l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass,@object # @"\01l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass"
    .align  8
l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass:
    .long   0                       # 0x0
    .long   8                       # 0x8
    .long   8                       # 0x8
    .zero   4
    .quad   0
    .quad   L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_
    .quad   l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MySuperClass
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .size   l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass, 72

    .type   OBJC_CLASS_$_MySuperClass,@object # @"OBJC_CLASS_$_MySuperClass"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_data","aw",@progbits
    .globl  OBJC_CLASS_$_MySuperClass
    .align  8
OBJC_CLASS_$_MySuperClass:
    .quad   OBJC_METACLASS_$_MySuperClass
    .quad   OBJC_CLASS_$_Object
    .quad   _objc_empty_cache
    .quad   _objc_empty_vtable
    .quad   l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MySuperClass
    .size   OBJC_CLASS_$_MySuperClass, 40

    .type   L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_1,@object # @"\01L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_1"
    .section    "__TEXT,__objc_classname,cstring_literals","aw",@progbits
L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_1:
    .asciz   "MyClass"
    .size   L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_1, 8

    .type   l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MyClass,@object # @"\01l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MyClass"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_const","aw",@progbits
    .align  8
l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MyClass:
    .long   1                       # 0x1
    .long   40                      # 0x28
    .long   40                      # 0x28
    .zero   4
    .quad   0
    .quad   L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_1
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .size   l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MyClass, 72

    .type   OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyClass,@object # @"OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyClass"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_data","aw",@progbits
    .globl  OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyClass
    .align  8
OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyClass:
    .quad   OBJC_METACLASS_$_Object
    .quad   OBJC_METACLASS_$_MySuperClass
    .quad   _objc_empty_cache
    .quad   _objc_empty_vtable
    .quad   l_OBJC_METACLASS_RO_$_MyClass
    .size   OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyClass, 40

    .type   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_2,@object # @"\01L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_2"
    .section    "__TEXT,__objc_methname,cstring_literals","aw",@progbits
L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_2:
    .asciz   "myMessage2"
    .size   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_2, 11

    .type   l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MyClass,@object # @"\01l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MyClass"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_const","aw",@progbits
    .align  8
l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MyClass:
    .long   24                      # 0x18
    .long   1                       # 0x1
    .quad   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_2
    .quad   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_TYPE_
    .quad   _2D__5B_MyClass_20_myMessage2_5D_
    .size   l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MyClass, 32

    .type   l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MyClass,@object # @"\01l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MyClass"
    .align  8
l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MyClass:
    .long   0                       # 0x0
    .long   8                       # 0x8
    .long   8                       # 0x8
    .zero   4
    .quad   0
    .quad   L_OBJC_CLASS_NAME_1
    .quad   l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MyClass
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .quad   0
    .size   l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MyClass, 72

    .type   OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass,@object # @"OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_data","aw",@progbits
    .globl  OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass
    .align  8
OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass:
    .quad   OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyClass
    .quad   OBJC_CLASS_$_MySuperClass
    .quad   _objc_empty_cache
    .quad   _objc_empty_vtable
    .quad   l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MyClass
    .size   OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass, 40

    .type   L_OBJC_LABEL_CLASS_$,@object # @"\01L_OBJC_LABEL_CLASS_$"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_classlist, regular, no_dead_strip","aw",@progbits
    .align  8
L_OBJC_LABEL_CLASS_$:
    .quad   OBJC_CLASS_$_MySuperClass
    .quad   OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass
    .size   L_OBJC_LABEL_CLASS_$, 16

    .type   L_OBJC_IMAGE_INFO,@object # @"\01L_OBJC_IMAGE_INFO"
    .section    "__DATA, __objc_imageinfo, regular, no_dead_strip","a",@progbits
    .align  4
L_OBJC_IMAGE_INFO:
    .long   0                       # 0x0
    .long   16                      # 0x10
    .size   L_OBJC_IMAGE_INFO, 8


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

My question is: how does the Objective-C runtime library, which must be linked against `test.o` so that the executable file can be successfully created, retrieves the methods list in order to create, for example, a vtable? Is it possible to use the `.section ..., @function`, `.section ..., @object` or `.section ..., @progbits` assembly directives to get this information, at least on linking time?

Comment: I found out that the `L_OBJC_LABEL_CLASS_$` label (at the end of the assembly file) is followed by a list of all implemented class addresses in array. This may be useful...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The compiler, linker, and runtime work together.

First, the compiler parses the source code for each class and emits directives like `.long`, `.zero`, and `.quad` describing the class's instance variables, properties, selectors, and methods.  The assembler turns these directives into raw data.

The data is in a format that the runtime understands.  For example, the data starting at symbol `OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass` matches the layout of the runtime's `struct class_t` (defined in [`objc-runtime-new.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-runtime-new.h)).  The data at symbol `l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MyClass` matches the layout of the runtime's `struct class_ro_t` (although most of the fields are 0 because the runtime updates them when it loads the class).  The `struct class_ro_t` has a `baseMethods` field of type `method_list_t *`, which in the case of `l_OBJC_CLASS_RO_$_MyClass` is initialized to `l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MyClass`.  At `l_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_MyClass` you will find data laid out like a `struct method_list_t`, which ends with an array of `struct method_t` - one for each method in the class.  In your example, it's not very interesting because each of your classes has only one method.

The compiler uses the `.section` directives to tell the linker how to group chunks of that data together.  For example, all of the `struct class_t` chunks will be put together in a section named `__objc_classlist`.  This way, the runtime can just look up the section named `__objc_classlist`, and then process the entire section as an array of `struct class_t`.  Take a look at the `GETSECT` macro in [`objc-file.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-file.mm).

The linker arranges for the function `_objc_init` (in [`objc-os.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-os.mm)) to run *very* early in the lifetime of your process, before `main`.  The `_objc_init` function registers some callbacks with the dynamic loader.  In particular, it tells the loader to call `map_images` (in [`objc-runtime-new.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm)), which calls `map_images_nolock`, which eventually calls `_read_images`.  The `_read_images` function actually parses those chunks of data emitted by the compiler and turns them into the data structures that `objc_msgSend` uses to actually send messages to objects.

[You can download an archive of the Mac OS X 10.8 Objective-C runtime source code](http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/objc4/objc4-532.tar.gz) to learn more.  This archive also contains source files for iOS/ARM (and even Windows!), although it might not correspond *exactly* to any version of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the runtime knows how to read your program, but that the objc front-end translates the code base to use the runtime.

Comment: yes, you're right, but the assembly code above is the one generated by the compiler to use the objective-c runtime (I think). It's got references to symbols that belong to the Objective-C runtime (`objc_msgSend_fixup`, `_objc_empty_cache` and `_objc_empty_vtable`, for example). But the `objc_msgSend_fixup` function, for instance, needs to get the methods of the classes and I imagine this is done by reading an specific section of the executable file. So, I want to know what section is this and how is this done.